# glibc detected; memory corruption

Tags: c++, memory-management, runtime-error

So this is very strange.. I'm using Halide (https://github.com/halide/Halide/), but the error I get is C++ related. When I run the code I get

```
*** glibc detected *** ./lesson_04: malloc(): memory corruption: 0x0000000000a36640 ***
```

It also prints "realizing" but doesn't print "blur initial". It works when I pass sigma equal to 1.0 but doesn't work for 2.0 or 3.0. This is a piece of a longer code. The longer code doesn't work even for 1. I don't understand how a value could influence anything and where it gets stuck. Any help? 
Thanks

```
#include <Halide.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#include "armadillo"
using namespace arma;

using namespace Halide;
#include "../apps/support/image_io.h"


Image<float> calculateGaussian(double sigmaD){
    int sigma=(int)sigmaD;
    Image<float> convolution(sigma*6+1,sigma*6+1); float sum=0;

    for (int i=-sigma*3; i<sigma*3+2; i++){
        for (int j=-sigma*3; j<sigma*3+2; j++){
            float r=std::sqrt(i*i+j*j);
            convolution(i+sigma*3,j+sigma*3)=std::exp(-r*r/(2*sigma*sigma));
            sum+=convolution(i+sigma*3,j+sigma*3);
        }
    }
    for (int i=0; i<sigma*6+1; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<sigma*6+1; j++){
            convolution(i,j)/=sum;
        }
    }
    return convolution;
}

Image<uint8_t> convolve(Image<uint8_t> im, Image<float> convolution){
    RDom r(convolution);
    int w=convolution.width(), h=convolution.height();
    int W=im.width(), H=im.height();
    Var x,y,c;
    Func blur, input;
    input(x, y,c) = im(clamp(x, 0, W-1), clamp(y, 0, H-1),c);   
    blur(x, y,c) = sum(cast<uint8_t>(convolution(r.x, r.y) * input(x + r.x - w/2, y + r.y - h/2,c)));
    Image<uint8_t> out=blur.realize(im.width(),im.height(),im.channels());
    return out;
}

Image<uint8_t> blurGaussian(Image<uint8_t> im, float sigma){
    printf("blur initial");
    Image<float> gaussian=calculateGaussian(sigma);

    return convolve(im,gaussian);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    Image<uint8_t> im1 = load<uint8_t>("../apps/images/stata-1.png");
    Image<uint8_t> output;
    printf("realizing \n");
    output=blurGaussian(im1,3.0);
    save(output, "blur.png");

    printf("Success!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you run the program in the debugger (gdb)? "blur initial" probably doesn't get printed because there's no "\n" on the end of the line so it's not getting flushed.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes output gets stuck in the write buffer and never actually gets written to the console if the program exits prematurely.  Calling `fflush(stdout);` will help you determine if this is the case.  Or else use `fprintf(stderr, ...)` for debug output, since `stderr` is unbuffered.

More likely, however, is that your program actually does crash inside the one major task that takes place between printing "realizing" and "blur initial"... the `Image<uint8_t>` copy constructor.

Why you're passing by value and causing a copy is beyond me, I would prefer a `const` reference there to avoid copying a large object.  Still, if you have a bug in your copy constructor it's definitely worth finding and fixing that first.

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite new to C++. What do you mean by const reference?

Comment: @Andrei: For example, change the function signature to `Image<uint8_t> blurGaussian(const Image<uint8_t>& im, float sigma)`

Comment: This doesn't seem to help(